# how to populate an array with return value objects

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

In the method below I add objects to an array using the switch-case.

```
-(void)addBall   {
    switch (ballKind)    {
        case greenBall:
        [ballArray addObject:[self createBallObject:CGPointMake(xPos*(s.width/480.0), yPos*(s.height/320.0)) ballStringName:@"greenBall.png"]];
        break;

    case redBall:
        [ballArray addObject:[self createBallObject:CGPointMake(xPos*(s.width/480.0), yPos*(s.height/320.0)) ballStringName:@"redBall.png"]];
        break;

    case blueBall:
        [ballArray addObject:[self createBallObject:CGPointMake(xPos*(s.width/480.0), yPos*(s.height/320.0)) ballStringName:@"blueBall.png"]];
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

createBallObject returns a CCPhysicsSprite. Also I have a method for returning the ballArray:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getBallArray    {

  return ballArray;
}
```

I want to access the CCPhysicsSprite return values for each of the createBallObjects within the ballArray (each ballArray element to be it's respective CCPhysicsSprite) and likewise their b2Body properties so I can iterate through them in a for loop. How can I achieve this?

Comment: why dont you return the `ballArray` in the `addBall` method, at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access one of the CCPhysicsSprite objects at a particular index of ballArray, do this:

```
int index; // Set this to which index of the array you wish to view.
CCPhysicsSprite *sprite = [ballArray objectAtIndex: index]);
```

If you want to access all the CCPhysicsSprite objects of ballArray, do this:

```
int count = [myColors count];

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    CCPhysicsSprite *sprite = [myColors objectAtIndex: count];
}
```

Hope this answers your question.